# Generate random 6-digit ID in Python

Tags: python, random

I have a database of questions. I want to mark them with **6-digit ID**.

I have tried using `uuid.uuid1()` with `int()` but it generates a 128-bit integer and that is too long.

I have also tried using `random()` but that random integer cannot have digit '0' as first digit.

The ID:

- Can start with digit '0'.
- There is a space between the first 3 digits and the last 3 digits.
- Must be unique (random ID).

For example, question 1 can be marked **050 124**

How can I create random ID like that?

Actually, the space between the first and last 3 digits is not important. So, if it's difficult, just show me how to create a random 6-digit number (can start with '0')

Comment: Please add a small snippet of your code, or any code that you have tried.

Comment: what did you try so far? + Unique and random are two different things.

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: what is the bigger picture here? why does it have to be random?

Comment: I have a database of questions and I want to mark them so the ID of each question must be unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This oneliner will do the trick:

```
import random

random_id = ' '.join([str(random.randint(0, 999)).zfill(3) for _ in range(2)])
```

But to achieve the uniqueness you need to know the details about how it may be checked for that. For example, if you're writing it to the database using raw SQL, you will need to check for uniqueness: for example, `SELECT id FROM my_table WHERE id=%s`, where `%s` is  your generated id. If it already exists, you need to generate it again. Basically you do something like this:

```
while True:
    uid = ' '.join([str(random.randint(0, 999)).zfill(3) for _ in range(2)])
    if uid_exists(uid):  # Your function to check if it already exist
        continue
write_your_record(uid)  # Do something next if not
```

P.S.: You will also need to guarantee uniqueness in terms of atomic operations. I. e. you could face a problem if other application/worker/etc. writes the same ID to the database in that moment when you've already checked that ID doesn't exist in the DB, but didn't write your record yet. You can do that in some different ways:

1)

If your ID column in the database is constrained as UNIQUE, you can rely on that:

```
while True:
    uid = ' '.join([str(random.randint(0, 999)).zfill(3) for _ in range(2)])
    try:
        write_your_record(uid)
        break
    except YourDatabaseAlreadyExistsError:
        continue
```

2. 

You can do all these actions inside a transaction, that locks the database from writing in parallel.

Comment: does it though?.. You have to do some padding as well; they way it now stands, it can return something like `97 341` which we do not want. I did not downvote for whatever its worth.

Comment: `random` is not defined, may not be clear to everyone what it is. Also, any generated three-digits number lower than 100 will not display the 0. Examples: `412 1` `25 609`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis oh, my bad, let me fix that

Comment: Sometimes I got an ID like this '72 92'. It should be '720 920', right? How can I fix that?

Comment: @Andrew-Vangeance I've already fixed it in my answer using `.zfill(3)`

Answer (score 2):

This should generate random numnbers that start with zero:

```
import numpy as np
''.join(map(str,np.random.randint(0,9,3))) + ' ' + ''.join(map(str,np.random.randint(0,9,3)))                                                                                        

# '050 645'
```

Comment: Why use numpy for such easy thing?

Answer (score 1):

Too long should not be a problem, you can always crop strings very easily. So let's say, your random() uuid() number would be in a variable `randNum`

```
ID = f"{randNum:06}"[-6:]
```

this will turn your random number into a string and add zeros to the beginning should the number be too short. It then takes only the last 6 digits. And if you insist on the space:

```
ID = f"{randNum:06}"
ID = ID[-6:-3] + " " + ID[-3:]
```

Comment: That is not an answer. Nothing about uniqueness and nothing about how to generate that `randNum`.

Comment: I beg to differ: this IS and Answer! Where do you get uniqueness from? that was not in the question... User asked "So, if it's difficult, just show me how to create a random 6-digit number (can start with '0')"... So that's what I showed -- and quite pythonic in my opinion ;-)